# What's the difference between the method .get() and the method .get in python? Both are appliable to dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

Imagine I have a dict.

```
d = ['a': 1 , 'b':3]
```

I'm having a hard time to understand the difference between `d.get` and `d.get()`.
I know that `d.get()` get the value from the key, like this:

```
print(d.get('a') )
```

output: 1

But when I write `d.get`, it shows this:

```
print(d.get)
```

output: <built-in method get of dict object at .........>

What is 'd.get' doing in my code?

I'm using python 3X

Comment: `d.get` is _literally_ the method/function.  That's what is trying to tell you with `<built-in method get of dict object`.  In python, methods are variables/properties just like any other value (like string, int, etc.).  P.S. `['a': 1 , 'b':3]` is not a dict.  It should be `{'a': 1 , 'b':3}`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks for the reply. I saw 'd.get' being used inside max('...', key= d.get). I know that 'max' accepts a key argument of a function, but I thought that I should use max('...', key = d.get()), because I didn't know that 'd.get' is a function and 'd.get()' is calling a function. Also, sorry thanks to pointing the error in my question about the right use of the synthax for a dictionaire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method is literally just an attribute of an object that happens to be of type `<class function>`. The output you see is essentially what happens when you try to call `print()` on *any* function object, and is essentially a concise string representation that python creates for the function.

Actually *calling* a function is done with parentheses: `d.get('a')`, which means to *execute the behavior the function refers to*. It doesn't especially matter where the function is, though: I could do the following, and it would still work:

```
d = {'a': 1 , 'b':3}
freefunc = d.get
freefunc('a')
```

This is what the term "first class functions" refers to, when people compare python to something like Java. An entire function can be encapsulated in a variable and treated no differently than any other variable or attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I searched a little about this topic, but I wasn't understanding it fully. Pretty dope the fact that functions are also objects.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer? There is no difference between the two methods. They are the same exact method.

The difference in your code is at when you write `.get()` you call the method, but when you write `.get` you just get a pointer (or location in the memory, to be exact) for that method, to call it later on if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In the first scenario, you are calling `print` on the result of executing `get('a')`, which in this case is 1.

In your second scenario, you are calling `print` on the `get` function itself, instead of on an execution of it, which evaluates to its documentation, i.e. `<built-in method get of dict object at...` etc.

Comment: Great explanation